# How to reorder dropdowns in django-admin inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to give some order to our django admin dashboard. At the moment I am able to order dropdowns by the field `name` using this code in `MyModelAdmin`:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "program":
        kwargs["queryset"] = models.ProgramModel.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

So, when I go to the `MyModel` I see the dropdown alphabetically ordered like in this image:

[image: ordered list in dropdown]

T)he problem is that if I bring that model as an Inline in a different model, it is not ordered anymore:

[image: unordered list in inline dropdown]

How can I have that dropdown ordered also in the inline element??

I already tried adding `ordering` to my `MyModel` meta class and it works, but I would like this to affect only the admin page and to be completely decoupled from the model.

---

The Inline class is just this:

```
class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    extra = 1
    model = models.Program.members.through
```

So I have the model `Program` with a m2m field to `Member`, through the model `Membership` (that I've been calling here `MyModel`).

Comment: Can you add `Inline` class which you are using?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `formfield_for_foreignkey` same way for inline class:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ProgramInline(admin.TabularInline):
    """Inline class"""  
    model = ProgramModel

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "program":
            kwargs["queryset"] = models.ProgramModel.objects.all().order_by('name')
        return super(ProgramInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Register program inline for some model"""
    inlines = [
        ProgramInline,
    ]
```

Comment: in that case I get this error in the last inline class line:


`Exception Value: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: @Nato522 oops, sorry it should be `return super(ProgramInline, self)`. Or in your case `return super(MyInline, self)`.

Comment: worked perfectly! Thank you! I was sure I tried this before haha anyway, thanks!